# Proof about properties of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove: If $a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+b=c+d$, then $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix}$ has integer eigenvalues. $$$$I need some help getting started. My idea is this: For there to be integer eigenvalues, $$(a+d)$$ and $$\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc}$$ must both be even, or must both be odd since division by $2$ will produce an integer this way. Note I am using the adaptation of the quadratic equation to the characteristic equation of a $2\times2$ matrix.

Also I see that the equation $a+b-(c+d)=0$ must be satisfied $\forall a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{Z}$.

Any other pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply note that for $a+b=c+d=\lambda_1$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
a+b\\
c+d\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\lambda_1\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

therefore, by definition, $\lambda_1$ is an (integer) eigenvalue for $A$ with eigenvector $(1,1)$.

Then observe that

- $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=Tr(A)=a+d \implies \lambda_2=a+d-\lambda_1$

Comment: This shows that one eigenvalue is an integer. To see that the other eigenvalue is also an integer, note that the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace $a+d$, which is an integer.

Comment: Yes of course, I didn't pointed out that but it is a very clever way to conclude! I add this step.